# django template inheritance not working everywhere

Tags: python, html, django, web-frameworks

I have a blog app and something is really bogging me. I have a base.html template that I extend in every template of my views and that works perfectly, just one of the views, which is the one that only shows the blog post and not the rest of the posts, doesn't extend the base.html even though I have the {% extends 'base.html'%} just as in every other template and everything else basically the same. Also static files aren't loading, even though I load them just as in every other template ..

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/favicon.ico" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            {% block title %}{% endblock %}
        </title>
    </head>
    <p class="header">Blog</p>

    <body background="static/landscape.jpg">
        <div class="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Other template(works):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block title %}Blog {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post">
        <h1>
            <a class ="title" href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">
                {{post.title}}
            </a>
        </h1>
        <p>{{post.content}}</p>

        <hr>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Specific template(doesn't work):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}{{post.title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1 style="font-size:40px;"> {{post.title}} </h1>
            <p>{{post.content|safe}}</p>
            <p class="date">
                Posted on
                <time datetime="{{post.created|date:"c"}}">
                {{post.created|date}}
                </time>
            </p>
        </header>

    </article>
    <hr>
{% endblock %}
```

I'd be very thankful if you can discover anything I can't ... thanks.

Comment: What does the directory structure look like where these files come from? I'm assuming all template files exist in `/path/to/templates` and `base.html` is in the top level. Where does the `specific template` live?

Comment: in path/to/templates/blog, where all the other templates live as well

Comment: So I guess define `doesn't work`. Does the page load and if so what is seen? Or are you getting an internal server error? Provide some more specifics about what isn't working.

Comment: The page loads just as long as any other view if that's what you mean, and the main difference is that I have the 'landscape.jpg' as my background image in base.html and that shows up in every other view, but in this one I just get a blank background. Everything from within {% block content %} shows up as usual, it's just the background image and also my CSS file isn't linked to the template, so I have to hardcode everything.

Comment: This really sounds like a path issue to me. Try adding a `/` to your css and background paths, for example: `<body background="/static/landscape.jpg">` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Cool, if you don't mind, I just copied my comment as an answer that you can accept. This way if someone else comes across it they can find the answer right away. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really sounds like a path issue to me. Try adding a `/` to your css and background paths, for example: `<body background="/static/landscape.jpg">` and see if that makes a difference.